# [Vue warn]: invalid template option:

Tags: vue.js

I'm using `vue router` to load components. The `Home` & `About` components load fine in the browser but the `Login` component fails to load and returns the error above.

[image]

**resources/js/components/LoginComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>login</h1>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

**resources/js/app.js**

```
import './bootstrap';

import LoginComponent from "./components/LoginComponent.vue";

const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>' }
const About = { template: '<div>About</div>' }

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/about', component: About },
    { path: '/login', component: LoginComponent } // edited
]

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
    // 4. Provide the history implementation to use. We are using the hash history for simplicity here.
    history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
    routes, // short for `routes: routes`
})

// 5. Create and mount the root instance.
const app = Vue.createApp({})

app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')
```

**app.blade.php**

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
            <h1>Hello App!</h1>
            <p>
                <!-- use the router-link component for navigation. -->
                <!-- specify the link by passing the `to` prop. -->
                <!-- `<router-link>` will render an `<a>` tag with the correct `href` attribute -->
                <router-link to="/">Go to Home</router-link>
                <router-link to="/about">Go to About</router-link>
                <router-link to="/login">Go to Login</router-link>
            </p>
            <!-- route outlet -->
            <!-- component matched by the route will render here -->
            <router-view></router-view>
```

Can you spot anything obvious as I'm stumped at the moment?

**Edit**:
[image]

Comment: remove `const Login = { template: LoginComponent }` LoginComponent is already a vue component with template, just pass it to the router `{ path: '/login', component: LoginComponent }`

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. However, this causes more problems when clicking on the links, above

Comment: search the error *[Vue warn]: Invalid VNode type: Symbol("Fragment") (symbol) at*

Comment: I think this is because of me trying to pull in two `vue-router` source files. Ive removed the hard-coded one from my html source, only now I'm back to an earlier error. `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-router.js?v=3d093063' does not provide an export named 'default'`

Comment: the above is generated from `import VueRouter from 'vue-router';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the correct usage of my particular versions of `vue` & `vue-router`

**resources/js/app.js**

```
import LoginComponent from "./components/LoginComponent.vue";

import './bootstrap';
const Home = { template: '<div>Home</div>' }

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/login', name: "Login", component: LoginComponent },
]
```

**resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
            <p>
                <router-link to="/">Go to Home</router-link>
                <router-link to="/login">Login</router-link>
            </p>

            <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the only readable answer is not what I needed, I repost @Lawrence Cherone's comment which is the correct answer in my case and probably in other people's case.

You have to **remove**

```
const Login = { template: LoginComponent }
```

Since LoginComponent **is already a vue component with template,**

just pass it to the router directly:

```
{ path: '/login', component: LoginComponent }
```